# assign column value based on multiple conditional criteria

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, subset

I have been trying to figure out how to assign a value based on some criteria.

I have a dataset that simplistically looks like:

```
fish <- data.frame ("method"=c("cryptic", "cryptic", "cryptic", 
                               "quad", "quad", "quad", 
                               "fish", 
                               "1mquad", "1mquad"),
                    "species"= c("A", "B", "C", 
                                 "A", "B", "D", 
                                 "A",
                                 "A", "B"), 
                  "cut"=1)
```

I want to change the value of cut to 0 if a species has both the method cryptic and quad or cryptic and 1mquad.

I've tried a few different things and keep getting stuck. When I do an if statement I get weird warnings. Some things I've tried are making a subset df with just cryptic

```
cryptic <- fish [fish$method == "cryptic",]
```

and then trying to subset

```
fish$cut [match(fish$species, cryptic$species) & fish$method =="quad"] <- 0
fish$cut [match(fish$species, cryptic$species) & fish$method =="1mquad"] <- 0
```

but that doesn't work. I also tried creating conditions:

```
cond3 <- fish$species %in% intersect(fish$species, cryptic$species)
cond4 <- fish$method %in% c ("1mquad", "quad", "cryptic")
```

and doing an if statement with that, but to no avail. Also, I have a few other conditions prior that changes cut to 0, so I can't use an ifelse statement because it overwrites those other conditions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close with the conditions. Here's an adjusted way:

```
crypt = unique(fish$species[fish$method == "cryptic"])
quad = unique(fish$species[fish$method %in% c("quad", "1mquad")])
to_change = intersect(crypt, quad)
fish$cut = ifelse(fish$species %in% to_change, 0, fish$cut)
fish
#    method species cut
# 1 cryptic       A   0
# 2 cryptic       B   0
# 3 cryptic       C   1
# 4    quad       A   0
# 5    quad       B   0
# 6    quad       D   1
# 7    fish       A   0
# 8  1mquad       A   0
# 9  1mquad       B   0
```

Using the `ifelse` statement with `fish$cut` as the "else" means that if the condition is not met, whatever is there will stay there.

### Demo

Comment: thanks so much! this worked perfect. and thanks for that help with the ifelse, it was driving me crazy because I thought it would just always overwrite haha